# ADO Download Latest and Previous Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to accomplish the following:

When I kick off a release of a build, I want to include the previous release with the latest one. What I am trying to do is run a script inside the release that compares the two files and outputs a combined file with additions and deletions highlighted. I have a script that will accomplish that, but im not entirely sure how to get yesterdays artifact with todays artifact do complete the release.

I was thinking about tagging but maybe someone has a creative idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using tags is a way to distinguish the dates of artifacts.

The artifact itself also has a parameter to distinguish between versions.

In Release Pipeline, you could add two artifacts from the same Build Pipeline.

For example:

[image]

The version of artifacts is distinguished by build number. You could select the Specific version and choose the target version for the two artifacts.

Then you could download the old and new artifacts in one release pipeline.

**Note:** You need to change the **Source Alias** for each artifacts. They need to be different.

Comment: Well, would there be any way to automate that? The script runs daily, and what I would like to accomplish for instance is: Today, build lets say is build 100 yesterday's build is 99. 99 and 100 are the consumed artifacts. tomorrow's build will be 101 and tomorrow 100 and 101 would be consumed and so-on and so-forth.

Comment: @ThomasC. I am afraid that there is no such method could meet your requirements. Currently, we can do this manually.  No related variables can change with the date

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the clarification and confirmation.

Comment: Hi @ThomasC. If the answer could give you some help, you may consider accepting it as answer. This will be helpful to other users.